# How do I tell if a Firebase App Check token is Valid using Cloud Function?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-app-check

Looking at the instructions from this page https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/cloud-functions

I can reject requests with:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions/v1");

exports.yourV1CallableFunction = functions
  .runWith({
      enforceAppCheck: true, // Reject requests with missing or invalid App Check tokens.
  })
  .https.onCall((data, context) => {
        // context.app contains data from App Check, including the app ID.
        // Your function logic follows.
        ...
  });
```

However, I do not want to reject the request. I only want to know if the app check token is valid. I will record that information and allow the user to continue in a limited way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check manually, you can follow the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/custom-resource-backend), however, you won't be able to use a callable type function since you don't get access to the incoming headers in the callback. You'd have to hack the Firebase Functions SDK in order to provide that for yourself. You can always fall back to HTTP type functions for more control over the request and response.